# JDBC setMaxRows making query much slower. Why?

Tags: jdbc, db2

I am trying to understand a situation I have with a query.

The query produces 54 records. If I set `setMaxRows(50)` the query takes 23s. If I set `setMaxRows(5000)` the query takes 0.4s. Removing the `setMaxRows` call also lets the query complete in 0.4s.

My code:

```
Connection conn = getConnection();

Statement s = conn.createStatement();
s.setMaxRows(max);
long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(QUERYPOSSTR));
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - t);
rs.close();
s.close();
conn.close();

static String QUERYPOSSTR = 
    "SELECT T.MMM FROM TABLE A, TABLE T " +
    "WHERE A.SSS = ' ' AND T.MMM = A.MMM AND T.SPRACHE = 'D' " +
        "AND T.TTT IN ( 'AB','AE','AV','A0','A1') AND A.LAND IN ( 'CN') " +
        "AND (A.JJJ >= 2010) AND POSSTR(T.AAA, '234') <> 0 " +
    "ORDER BY A.MMM, T.TTT, T.LFDNR ASC";
```

What is `setMaxRows` actually doing here? It seems that choosing the 'wrong' value causes the query to take 50-60 times as long! Am I using it incorrectly?

**UPDATE**
Ran the tests again with different values for max row:

```
Statement with POSSTR. Max=54
    Complete in 22,62 sec
    Row count = 54
Statement with POSSTR. Max=55
    Complete in 22,61 sec
    Row count = 54
Statement with POSSTR. Max=60
    Complete in 23,36 sec
    Row count = 54
Statement with POSSTR. Max=100
    Complete in 0,90 sec
    Row count = 54
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is answerable without knowledge of how `setMaxRows` is implemented in this specific JDBC driver. Looking at the JDBC spec, a driver should just stop returning rows after the value of `setMaxRows` has been reached, but based on your description the driver attempts to restrict the number of rows queried, which might lead to a sub-optimal query plan. But without knowledge of the implementation, that is just a guess, and I am afraid that IBM won't be answering this here.

Comment: Another reason could be that values < 100 are fetched at once and then it may have to consume the rest of the result set internally, while if you specify 100 or more, the 'performance hit' will only be when you fetch the 100th row. As your code doesn't seem to process the result set, it might simply be an unfair comparison.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - thanks for the reply. I deliberately did not process the result set as I don't think that is relevant to this problem. What concerns me is that the `executeQuery` time varies depending on what value of `setMaxRows` is used. The admins have traced the query and say that the query plan is the same, irrespective of the `setMaxRows`value. Guess I'll be opening a ticket with IBM...

Comment: As I said the difference may well lie with the default fetch size of the driver. If the driver fetches rows in batches of 75 rows, then a maxRows of 75 might have a different effect than 76 if (just a theory!) the protocol requires that entire record stream to be consumed. Say you set it maxRows=76, the default fetch size=75. The first execute fetches 75 rows, after 76x `next()` it fetches 1 more row and then proceeds to consume the remaining rows; with maxRows=75: the first execute fetch 75 rows and then proceeds to consume the remaining rows.